# Speed of the x265 and ffmpeg HEVC based encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding

I'm trying to perform a real-time encoding of a video using HEVC with ffmpeg. I'm able to achieve the required performance when running the x265 encoder separately without the support of ffmpeg. This way the my system can perform the encoding at 30 frames per second. However, my requirement is to create a MPEG-TS stream with the encoded content and therefore, the video is encoded with the ffmpeg as follows:

> ffmpeg -s:v 1280x720 -i input.yuv -c:v libx265 -x265-params crf=20:keyint=25:fps=25:preset=ultrafast -f mpegts out.ts

Strangely, the performance of the encoding is reduced drastically and I'm only able to achieve an encoding performance of just 10 frames per second.

Is this a problem of the multiplexing process within ffmpeg?. Could someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I find using ffmpeg defaults, a x265 encode takes much longer than x264. If I can achieve 40fps on x264, it reduce down to 10fps using x265. x265 is computationally more intensive than x264 to achieve a smaller file with similar quality.

Answer (score 0):

This is can be a reason q factor in FFmpeg. You need to compare q value of FFmpeg and x265 bin. This is my guess.